# Scraping a dynamically/Javascript generated website with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape this website:

http://stats.uis.unesco.org/unesco/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=210

using Python and Selenium (see code below). The content is dynamically generated, and apparently data which is not visible in the browser is not loaded. I have tried making the browser window larger, and scrolling to the bottom of the page. Enlarging the window gets me all the data I want in the horizontal direction, but there is still plenty of data to scrape in the vertical direction. The scrolling appears not to work at all.

Does anyone have any bright ideas about how to do this?

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "http://stats.uis.unesco.org/unesco/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=210"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(5) # wait to load

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

table = soup.find("table", {"id":"DataTable"})

### get data
thead = table.find('tbody')
loopRows = thead.findAll('tr')
rows = []
for row in loopRows:
rows.append([val.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for val in  row.findAll(re.compile('td|th'))])
with open("body.csv", 'wb') as test_file:
  file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
  for row in rows:
      file_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What exact data are you trying to extract from this page?

Comment: Is downloading the report data via the actions menu not an option?

Comment: @Virendra Rajput: I want Adult (15+) literacy rate (%). Total for all years and countries

Comment: @scdove: If you can automate the download via the action menu then you will be my hero of the day, and I would forever be in your debt. :)

Answer (score 5):

This will get you as far as autosaving the entire csv to disk, but I haven't found a robust way to determine when the download is complete:

```
import os
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import csv
import time

url = "http://stats.uis.unesco.org/unesco/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=210"
download_dir = '/tmp'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
# 2 means "use the last folder specified for a download"
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-csv")

# driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("onDownload(2);")
    csvfile = os.path.join(download_dir, 'download.csv')

    # Wait for the download to complete
    time.sleep(10)
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
            print(line)
```

---

**Explanation:**

Point your browser to `url`.
You'll see there is an `Actions` menu with an option to `Download report data...` and a suboption entitled `"Comma-delimited ASCII format (*.csv)"`. If you inspect the HTML for these words you'll find

```
"Comma-delimited ASCII format (*.csv)","","javascript:onDownload(2);"
```

So it follows naturally that you might try getting `webdriver` to execute the JavaScript function call `onDownload(2)`. We can do that with

```
driver.execute_script("onDownload(2);")
```

but normally another window will then pop up asking if you want save the file. To automate the saving-to-disk, I used the method described in [this FAQ](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile). The tricky part is finding the correct MIME type to specify on this line:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-csv")
```

The `curl` method described in the FAQ does not work here since we do not have a url for the csv file. However, [this page](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/) describes another way to find the MIME type: Use a Firefox browser to open the save dialog. Check the checkbox saying "Do this automatically for files like this". Then inspect the last few lines of `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/mimeTypes.rdf` for the most recently added description:

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:application/x-csv"
                   NC:alwaysAsk="false"
                   NC:saveToDisk="true">
    <NC:externalApplication RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:application/x-csv"/>
  </RDF:Description>
```

This tells us the mime type is `"application/x-csv"`. Bingo, we are in business.

Comment: Nice, that works. Additionally, I've been having trouble with setting Firefox download preferences, which this also solves. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to find the MIME type in Chrome is to hit F12, then click on the _network_ tab. Then download the file. Sometimes the server does not publish the correct type, as I just found out when trying to download an .xls file with MIME type 'application/octet-stream'

Answer (score 0):

You can do the scrolling by

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("html body.TVTableBody table#pageTable tbody tr td#cell4 table#MainTable tbody tr td#vScrollTD img[onmousedown='imgClick(this.sbar.visible,this,event);']").click()
```

It seems like once you can scroll the scraping should be pretty standard unless I'm missing something